# Collection with record level locking?

Tags: java

I need to make a data structure keyed off of username and then some data (additional collections) in a POJO. The data needs to be thread safe.

So I'm thinking for the main structure, `ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyPOJO>`. For the operations I need to perform on MyPOJO, I may either just read it, or I may perform write operations on it.

Would the best approach be to do a get on the map and then operate on MyPOJO in a syncronized block? I assume I just need to put a syncronized block in the update methods and the read methods would automatically be blocked? Is that the best approach in a highly concurrent app? Or do I need to use something like ReadWriteLock on BOTH the get/set operations?

If I use something like StampedLock, each MyPOJO would need one correct, so I can do record level locking?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking for a way to atomically update the map and your POJO? That doesn't exist in the JDK, you'll have to write your own synchronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would the best approach be to do a get on the map and then operate on MyPOJO in a `synchronized` block?

I assume that you mean a `synchronized` block on the `MyPOJO` instance itself (or a private lock owned by the instance).

My answer is yes, if you do it right.

> I assume I just need to put a `synchronized` block in the update methods and the read methods would automatically be blocked?

No, that's not correct.  All methods that access or update a mutable object would need to synchronize on the same lock.

If you don't synchronize for both reads and writes, you risk various thread-safety concerns, including problems with visibility of writes.  Heisenbugs.

> Is that the best approach in a highly concurrent app?  Or do I need to use something like `ReadWriteLock` on BOTH the get/set operations?

It depends.

On the `ReadWriteLock` issue:

- Unless it is likely that you will get *significant* lock contention on a specific `MyPOJO` instance, it is probably not worth the effort to optimize this.
- If the access and update methods only hold the lock for a relatively short period of time, that reduces the impact of any contention.

More generally, I have a suspicion that you might be confusing "highly concurrent" with "highly scalable".  Java multi-threading only performs up to the limit of the cores (and memory) on a single machine.  Beyond that, clever tweaks to improve concurrency get you nowhere.  To scale up further, you need to change the system architecture so that requests are handled by multiple JVM instances on different machines.

So ... to sum up ... `ReadWriteLock` might help if you have significant contention on individual `MyPOJO` instances AND there are likely to be a lot of parallel read operations on individual instances.

> If I use something like `StampedLock`, each `MyPOJO` would need one correct, so I can do record level locking?

I doubt that there would be much benefit unless you have significant contention; see above.  But yes, if you used a `StampedLock` per instance you would get record-level locking ... just like you would other per-instance locking.

---

FWIW: This smells to me of "premature optimization".  Furthermore, if you expect that your solution will need to scale beyond a single JVM in the short to medium term, then it is arguably a waste of time to optimize the single JVM solution too much.

Comment: its a take home "project" ;)... yes, I would say the requirements read multi-threaded environment... sounds like a read/write lock might show more "initiative" ;). Thanks.

Comment: Initiative == premature optimization?  On of the concerns is that a premature optimization may actually be an anti-optimization.